# Include c++ libraries in uwp C#

Tags: c#, c++, uwp, windows-10-universal

my app is developed in C#. We have a WinRT component, which uses the c++ libraries. After adding a reference from C# project to WinRT, everything is fine. Compilation without errors. But if I try to create new object, I get exception FileNotFound. The reason is, WinRT component doesn't have dependency dlls. So I tried to add them in project, set Content = true, but it is not working. The libraries are not included in the package, so are not deployed to mobile emulator. When I try to run the app on desktop, it's not working too. I have to copy the dlls manually to Appx folder.

Please let me know, if you have some advice for me.

Thank you